# Getting value from SelectedItem to other method

Tags: c#, wpf, variables, row, radgridview

So I have `RadGridView` with `ContextMenu` that has `ItemClick` event with this code :

```
ListData selectedItem = new ListData();    
public void GridContextMenu_ItemClick(object sender, Telerik.Windows.RadRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MenuItem item = (e.OriginalSource as RadMenuItem).DataContext as MenuItem;
        switch (item.Text)
        {
            case "Edit":
                selectedItem = (GridView.SelectedItem);
                editMenu.Show();
                this.Close();
                break;
            case "Delete":
                this.GridView.Items.Remove(this.GridView.SelectedItem);
                break;
        }
    }
```

The `ListData` is something like this :

```
public class ListData
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    ...
    public string Something { get; set; }
}
```

I know that `selectedItem` inside case"Edit" has one row data from Name, Type, ... , Something from the clicked row when i click the "Edit" Menu. But how can i use the `selectedItem` in other method in the same .xaml.cs or even in other file?

Comment: *"But how can i use the selectedItem in other method in the same .xaml.cs or even in other file?"* - This is quite vague, can you provide any more information on exactly what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: If selectedItem was declared at the top of the class it should be in scope for other methods to use.  Also `ListData` is not the same as `AssetListData`. Be sure they are spelled the same way.

Comment: @dev1998 sorry for the late reply, yes i edit it the ListData. i tried to declare it at the top of the class. but when i call it in the other class it values are empty

Answer (score 0):

OK, I'm not sure if this is exactly what you need, but here is what worked for me.

At the top of the class I have this :`public ListData selectedItem;`

Inside the class constructor I have this: `selectedItem = new ListData();`
and also this `public ObservableCollection<ListData> OCLData;`

I created a datagrid named dgMirza, and set the ItemsSource = OCLData. OCLData is a collection of ListData objects.

Inside the SelectedCellsChanged event I put this: `selectedItem = (ListData)dgMirza.SelectedItem;`

I was able to see data in the selectedItem object even in other methods.